# How can I print the error message from a try block in a catch block using TryCatch.pm?

Tags: perl, try-catch

I have a try-catch block (from the [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch) module) in my script and I want to print the error message from the `try` block in the `catch` block. It seems like the error variable is local to the `try` block:

```
use TryCatch;
...
try {
        some command;
    }
    catch {
        print "some command failed due to: $@";
        # error variable $@ is not visible here
        return;
    }
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you are using Try::Tiny, within the `catch {}` block the error will be found in `$_`.

Comment: Try::Catch does it the same way: `$_`, and TryCatch exposes `$@` (per its docs)

Comment: @DavidO The TryCatch docs are wrong about `$@`, see [this ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=49072). Based on the number of unfixed issues, I would use Try::Tiny instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch#SYNTAX), the code you've shown should work. However, there's a [longstanding bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=49072) that causes it to fail.

You can get around it by using a signature in the `catch` block:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use TryCatch;

try {
    die 'foo';
}
catch ($err) {
    say "Caught $err";
}
```

Output:

```
Caught foo at ./bar line 10.
```

However, based on the number of [outstanding bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=TryCatch), I would recommend using [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) instead.